# Verify asymptotics as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose $x_n\in \left(1,1+\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Does this imply 
$$
x_n\sim 1+\frac{\log n}{n}\text{as }n\to\infty?
$$

---

My answer is "yes" since 
$x_n\in \left(1,1+\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$. Also $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=1$ for $y_n:=1+\frac{\log n}{n}$.

Because the limits of the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(1/y_n)$ exists (both are 1), we can compute
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n\cdot \frac{1}{y_n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/y_n)=1\cdot 1=1.   (*)
$$

But $(*)$ is what is meant with the notation
$$
x_n\sim y_n \text{as }n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: You are fully correct and your justification is fully rigorous. +1

Comment: If $x_n \sim 1$ then $x_n \sim 1 + z_n$ for any $z_n \to 0$.